# How to upgrade application to the latest version using yum in Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

I have Fedora 15, and Gnome 3. But i would like to update to the latest version of Gnome 3 (where  i have 3.0.1 always). For some error reason i must need to upgrade to Gnome 3.0.3

How do we update Fedora for a specific application or group applications to latest version?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

`yum install @group-name`

`yum groupinstall group1 [group2] ...`

Or you should try running the graphical package manager and update the entire group.

**EDIT1**

Currently GNOME3.0.2 is the latest. The GNOME3.0.2 is still not available from the fedora repositories. You need to manually compile the binaries to get it.

**EDIT2**

Got from #fedora freenode channel: Check this : http://osdir.com/ml/fedora-announce/2011-05/msg01634.html

`yum update gnome-shell`

Comment: @phoxis: I tried that but still i get Gnome 3.0.1 instead of latest 3.0.3 yum groupupdate "GNOME Desktop Environment" "Development Tools" "Server Configuration Tools" "Hardware Support" "Sound and Video" "Graphical Internet" "Fonts" "Games and Entertainment" "Printing Software" "Administration Tools" "Office/Productivity" "System Tools" --skip-broken

Comment: GNOME3.0.3 is not released yet. check the answer update.

Comment: @phoxis: still no luck. # yum update gnome-shell
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: as you see, it is not still available from the fedora repositories. If you want it then either wait for it to come into the fedora15 repos, or compile from source.

Comment: Compile from the source is always problem with Fedora. I will give a try if not then i will change my desktop from Gnome 3 to Xfce. Because Gnome 3 is not working for many issues.